# What are the differences between Django and Express.js?

Tags: python, node.js, django, express

Since, Django and Express.js are both web frameworks for Python and Node.js respectively. So, This is a very basic difference between them. But, there might be other important differences. So, if somebody can explain that here, it will be very beneficial to me.